# 404 Error - Unable to add non CMS page in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I tried creating a non CMS page in Magento 1.9.
I followed these steps :

Created a folder called 'Returns' in app/code/local and within it created another sub folder called 'Returns' with 2 folders 'controller' and 'etc'in it.

Within controller, I created a file called 'ReturnsController.php' and filled it as below -

```
  <?php class Returns_Returns_ReturnsController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
public function returnsAction()
{
    //Get current layout state
    $this->loadLayout();

    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
        'returns',
        array('template' => 'returns/returns.phtml')
    );

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->setTemplate('page/1column.phtml');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session'); 
    $this->renderLayout();
}}
```

?>

Then in 'etc', I created a file 'config.xml' with content as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Returns_Returns>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Returns_Returns>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <returns_returns>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Returns_Returns</module>
                    <frontName>returns</frontName>
                </args>
            </returns_returns>          
        </routers>              
    </frontend>

</config>
```

After this, I created a file in app/etc/modules as Returns_Returns.xml with content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Returns_Returns>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Returns_Returns>
    </modules>    
</config>
```

Finally, I added a folder called 'returns' in app/design/frontend/et_oxynic/default/template. Created a file called 'returns.phtml' in it with test content

```
<?php 
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):
  $name = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName();
endif;
?>

<div class="box">
  <div class="box-content">
    <h4>
      <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): echo "Welcome" . $name . "!"; ?>
      <?php else:  echo "Welcome, Guest!"; endif; ?>
    </h4>
    <p>We have successfully created a page using a magento module and router!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cleared the cache from cache management from admin but I still get a 404 error.

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You also need a layout file for your `returns` action at
`app/design/frontend/et_oxynic/default/layout/`

Let's call it `returns.xml` ;)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <returns_returns_returns>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="core/template" name="returns" template="returns/returns.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </returns_returns_returns>
    </layout>
```

Comment: Thanks Kalpesh ! But its still not working..I cleared the cache as well after adding this file. Is there anything else I might be missing ?

Comment: I just noticed you said you created `controller` folder, it should be `controllers`